# recording audio in iPad/iPhone through browsers

Tags: gwt, cordova

We are developing a application in GWT. It needs to cater to different clients which include iPad, iPhone, Android and desktop clients. And there is a requirement to record the audio. How can this be achieved on mobile devices? Looks like PhoneGap provides a API for this but it has to be deployed as native application in the end which may be problematic in long run due to multiple versions(one on each app store) and issues with updates etc. Is there any way this can be achieved on mobile browsers using GWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, there's no easy solution for this. The GWT compiler creates Javascript, and since there's currently no way to record audio using just javascript, GWT can't do it natively. On a desktop, it could be achieved by way of a Java applet, but that won't work for Android or Apple devices.

You might, however, have a look at [gwtmobile-phonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwtmobile-phonegap/), which claims to be able to "Record and play back audio files."

As you said, you still have to deal with updates and multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

The [Media Capture API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/) should be able to do this. However, Android seems to be the only mobile OS currently supporting it ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Capture_API)).

Comment: The Media Capture API is only supported by Android 3.0+, which is present on about 2.4% of all Android devices. I would hesitate to call that "currently supporting it".